# Is it possible to get google api access token by using any REST API Client

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am looking for tips or tutorial where I can fetch data from youtube data api.

By using only api key, I can use any rest api client in order to fetch many informations from https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels.

And now, I would like to get **auditDetails** which needs authorization token https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#auth.

**[Edit]**

By following the steps [below (Using OAuth guides)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps), I can now make request but I have an error 400 which is redirect_uri_mismatch:

**The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:9874, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client**

In my console developer configuration, I set the redirect authorized url to http://localhost/authorize.php

So I do not understand why during the authentification, it uses http://localhost:9874

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855306/8327971) for a top level description of OAuth authorization -- that includes the top info about access tokens and the related refresh tokens. Note that you need to go through the official docs referred therein.

Comment: After following the steps from the link bellow, I got an error redirect_uri_mismatch