# Youtube API: Download and upload playlists

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'd like to manage the playlists on my account automatically with a program I'm going to write. To this end, I took a look at the youtube API. However, it seems to me that the only sensible way to do that is to have a Google G Suite account in order to get access to the OAuth 2.0 API. At the same time, it confuses me that I need to pay a monthly fee just to be able to manage my own playlists. Am I missing something or is this indeed the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have to pay anything for normal operations (e.g. if you're able to function within the boundaries of the default [quota allocated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) to your app). To manage (ie. list/create/modify/delete) your channel's playlists you'll have to use the following API endpoints:

- [`Playlists.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list), [`Playlists.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert), [`Playlists.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/update) and [`Playlists.delete`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/delete);
- [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list), [`PlaylistItems.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert), [`PlaylistItems.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/update) and [`PlaylistItems.delete`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete).

For read-only operations on public data it suffices to have an application key.

For write operations you'll have to familiarize yourself with OAuth 2.0 authorization in the context of this API. See a brief top level description given by [one of my recent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855306/8327971). Then you'll have to go through the official docs referred to therein.