# Missing credentials while calling YouTube insert API

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to use API key instead of OAuth token to call insert API from YouTube v3 lib. Code snippet is like below:

```
await google
.youtube("v3")
.videos.insert({
    key: "my-youtube-api-key",
    part: "id,snippet,status",
    notifySubscribers: false,
    requestBody: {
    snippet: {
        title: "Test video title",
        description: "Test video description",
    },
    status: {
        privacyStatus: "public",
    },
    },
    media: {
    body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
    },
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log("Upload to YouTube failed", err);
    return null;
});
```

However, I am hitting error code 401, message is:

```
  code: 401,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Login Required.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'required',
      location: 'Authorization',
      debugInfo: 'Authentication error: missing credentials.',
      locationType: 'header'
    }
  ]
```

How can I fix this issue? Isn't API key not supported? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#auth), it's insufficient to use an API key on [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) endpoint; you'll have to be properly authorized to call this endpoint:

> **Authorization**
>
> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)).
>
> **Scope**
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl

Comment: But I'm using a server key. Isn't it sufficient?

Comment: OAuth 2.0 authentication is the only way the API *allows resources to be changed*. API keys are useful only for *read-only operations on public-data* (e.g. with an API key one cannot read info that is private to any given resource).

Comment: hmm, but if I use my own account to set up the OAuth 2.0, do I have to do manual login every time I want to upload any video? Will the token automatically get refreshed?

Comment: No, you don't. Please read carefully [one of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855306/8327971) on this issue, along with the official docs referred to therein.

Comment: hmm, coincidently, I am doing this on server side, and it seems I won't have the browser access neither. I'm using firebase cloud function to trigger this video insert event. Do you think I have any workaround to do so?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no workaround that could be applied. You'll have to obtain a *refresh token* on a desktop computer (that has a browser installed, following the procedure described by [this doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps); after that, move in a secure way your refresh token to your server, such that your program to trade with the API that token (each time needed) for an *access token*. This latter token (which is short-lived) will be passed on to `Videos.insert` API endpoint as a HTTP header of form `Authorization: Bearer access_token`.

Comment: This procedure will work one hundred percent; no workaround; everything as per the official docs, thus in compliance with [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies).