# Upload video to Youtube from firebase using cloud function to only one specific channel

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My application in a nutshell:
Client will upload video to my firebase storage.
Using cloud functions I want to move the video file from firebase storage to Youtube.
All the Youtube videos should be under one channel (my channel). I don’t need client side authentication as the client should not interact with my Youtube channel.
Essentially, Youtube here is acting as a **private** video storage platform (only for this use case and not the end result for the application).

I tried to upload the video to Youtube just as I saw in [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/youtube/upload.js).

The logs points to an issue with the `redirects_uri`.
I'm not sure why I need redirect URL, the authentication shouldn’t matter here since I have only one "user" (firebase) uploading to it's own channel.

I think I'm doing something wrong here with the authentication. I need to know:

- Do I need redirect URL for the above use case?
- Is it possible to move the video in a different method? (it's all Google after all and I'm using the same user)
- I remember I saw an old use case where you were able to upload to your own channel just with the id and the password of the channel, is it still possible?
- Does Youtube API support only server side authentication to only one user that associated with that channel?

Since I'm using firebase storage I wonder if I can use temporary Signed URL as the path to my video file:

```js
let expires = new Date();
expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000));

const downloadUrlArr = await videoFile.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: expires
})
const downloadUrl = downloadUrlArr[0];


const res = await youtube.videos.insert(
{
    part: 'id,snippet,status',
    notifySubscribers: false,
    requestBody: {
      snippet: {
        title: fileName,
        description: 'Testing YouTube upload via Google APIs Node.js Client',
      },
      status: {
        privacyStatus: 'private',
      },
    },
    media: {
      body: fs. createReadStream(downloadUrl),
    },
},
```

I tired to look for an answers to the above but it's always the same steps:
Get your google credentials to your project,
Get the token and refresh token (which I can’t since I don’t have valid redirect URL).

I can't have the browser throw an authentication request to the client (plus I don’t need the client user data or access to it), it needs to be handled in the backend.

Comment: Your premise (quote) *Youtube here is acting as a **private** video storage platform* is very much wrong: there are several reasons implying that to be so. You should get acquainted with at least the [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies) specifications.

Comment: @stvar Thanks, the final results should be measuring performance of video stream so in the above use case I just need help to store the video in Youtube. After I upload the video to Youtube I think I can manage to stream it in my application. I already managed to do it with Publitio and api.video I want to see if Youtube can provide better performance or easier implementation/control.

Comment: Here is an answer you may well be interested reading: [YouTube Data API v3: video upload from server without opening the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855306/8327971).

Comment: W.r.t. (quote) *After I upload the video to Youtube I think I can **manage to stream it** in my application*, I'd recommend once again to read the DTOS document I quoted above. Streaming a YouTube video is illicit activity -- apart from playing that video with YouTube's own Player API.

Comment: @stvar, I meant using Youtube player in my application. Thanks