# How to automate OAuth2.0 in Youtube Data API?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am working with YouTube Data API v3,
am using PythonAnywhere as hosting server for my Python script, and I have no idea how to automate getting access token to OAuth2:

```json
    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
```

The problem is that the function prints the link to console, so I can't get it inside my code and for example automate getting token with selenium.

Is there any way to change output from console to something else (file or variable) or if its impossible, is there any way to automate getting OAuth 2.0 access token?

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [YouTube Data API v3: video upload from server without opening the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855306/8327971).