# How can I upload videos into my youtube account without oAuth consent screen using YT data API v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to upload local videos into my youtube account through my web app without oAuth consent screen. I am using node js as server and react js as frontend.

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [YouTube Data API v3: video upload from server without opening the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855306/8327971).

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between private and public data.  Public data is data that is not owned by any user and is available publicly.
Methods like Search List for example access public data available on YouTube.

Private data is data that is owned by a user.  In order to upload to your YouTube account you need permission to upload to that account.

The [Videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) method as you can see by the documentation requires that the user have consented to your application accessing their YouTube account. They must have consented to your access with one of the following scopes.

[image]

So the answer to your question is that you cant. You need to consent to authorization before your application is going to be allowed to upload to YouTube

## upload public videos

Please remember that all videos uploaded via the videos.insert endpoint from unverified API projects created after 28 July 2020 will be restricted to private viewing mode. To lift this restriction, each API project must undergo an audit to verify compliance with the Terms of Service. Please see the API Revision History for more details.

Your application will need to go though application verificatin process before any of the videos you upload will be public

Comment: thank you for your answer. could you please tell me how can I verify my application.